# Comparing strings in Apache Velocity templates (AWS AppSync)

Tags: serverless, aws-appsync, vtl

I am wanting to compare strings and am unable to. Consider this example:

```
#set($foo = "a")
#set($bar = "a")

#if($foo == $bar) // Not the same
#if($foo == $bar.toString()) // The same
#if($foo.toString() == $bar) // The same
```

If I cast a single one then it matches?

The example on Apache site shows similar use (though there is a typo saying neither choice will ever match)

```
#set ($foo = "deoxyribonucleic acid")
#set ($bar = "ribonucleic acid")

#if ($foo == $bar)
  In this case it's clear they aren't equivalent. So...
#else
  They are not equivalent and this will be the output.
#end
```

They do mention casting as string when items are of diff class of course but this is not my case.

What's going on? I am doing this on Serverless Framework using the AppSync Local plugin. Could the issue be there?

**Update** Potentially a bug in [awsutils offline app sync package](https://github.com/ConduitVC/aws-utils/tree/appsync/packages/appsync-emulator-serverless). Bug report filed. Stay tuned.

Comment: I tested this on AppSync (server) and it works correctly i.e all 3 statements are equivalent. Could this be a bug with the Serverless Framework or the AppSync Local plugin?

Comment: I just dove into that AppSync local code and it seems to use velocityjs package which works fine with same test. Not sure what's going on here.